# pass textbox from one activity to other

Tags: c#, textbox, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is that possible to pass a textbox user input data from activity1 to activity2?
i tried this but it didn't work.

```
var second = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondPage));
second.PutExtra("reg", "qwe");
StartActivity (second);
```

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What didn't work? Are you fetching that info on the other activity?

```
public class SecondPage : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        var reg = this.Intent.Extras.GetString("reg");

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.second_layout);

        var textView = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.secondText);

        textView.Text = reg;
```

This is the XML for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55.2dp"
        android:id="@+id/secondText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer but I would suggest running through some more Xamarin examples.

Comment: Worked for me thanks. But if I'm trying to do it with int .tostring() its do an error do you know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
var second = new Intent (this, typeof(SecondPage));
                second.PutExtra ("value",i);
                StartActivity (second);
```

On the SecondPage activity:

```
string Passed_value;
  Passed_value  = Intent.GetStringExtra ("value");
```

for int use:

```
int Passed_value;
Passed_value  = Intent.GetIntExtra ("value",0);
```